# Clean DOM orphan-nodes leak with JS

Tags: javascript, jsf, dom, memory-leaks

I faced memory leak problem in my app. Memory growth was up to 200 mb in 30 minutes of work, so I investigated memory heap and found out what the reason was in DOM orphan-nodes, that's for some unknow reason didnt collect by browser GC.
[image]
Maybe someone can help with some javascript function thats detect all oprhan nodes in my DOM and clean them? That's be better solution for me, cause I got java's jsf RichFaces library, and all that's dom orphan nodes comes due using they ajax tags and I think this cant be prevented, due unable of library's code editing.

Or maybe there can be other solutions? Thnks.

**UPDATE1.** Whats strange to me: memory leak problems comes only after 30 minutes of work, I compared memory heap in first second of work and after 30 minutes, and I didnt see orphan-nodes growth. My image below compares difference between 30 minutes(left side) and 1 hour(right side).

Comment: I'd recommend re-using those nodes as much as possible. Keep a pool of available discarded nodes, and select nodes from the pool if you need to create new nodes. Similar to the [Object Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)

Comment: pls, see my edits to answer, that's no better way for me

Comment: Do you have access to the code that is creating these orphaned nodes? Are you using a framework for DOM manipulation?

Comment: I think that comes when page reload some elements(blocks) with ajax in time before  they fully loaded, but I can fault. See my update1

Comment: Are you using a framework like jQuery or Angular?

Comment: I can use jQuery, if that helps me to write some function that clean my orphan nodes from DOM in some time interval